# Serializing iPhone Navigation Control Stack

Tags: iphone, serialization, navigationcontroller

Can we Serialize the iPhone Navigation controller's stack to save the state? Is it allowed by Apple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saving the stack is as easy as reading the list of controllers pushed to the navigation controller and serializing them:

```
NSArray *myStack = [self.navigationController viewControllers]
```

I can't remember explicit guidelines from Apple that require developers not to do such a thing.

Answer (score 0):

can you give us more hint, why you want to do that? Is this for saving the user selection in the navigation controller? If I were you, I would save the class name by doing

```
[[myControllerObj class] description]
```

and save it somewhere like NSUserDefault, later if you want to push it again to stack then you need

```
NSString* className = @"MyControllerClass";
MyControllerClass* obj = (MyControllerClass*) [[NSClassFromString(className) alloc];
[myNavigation pushViewController: obj];
```

hope helps

:)